# Postgresql giving previous date(server in USA) even if I am using query with timezone- getting previous date instead of today date

Tags: postgresql, timezone

I am using a server hosted in Houston USA and there PostgreSQL 8.4.20 is installed. I am using the services from India . So for getting IST as datetime I am using the query as follows:

```
select current_date AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Kolkata'
```

Suppose the date time in India is: `2016-02-05 11:00:00`

When I am getting by using the query as `2016-02-04 11:00:00` .

Why I am getting Server date?

I am using IST here. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres (like MySQL and a few others) has a concept of a "session time zone".  You simply need to set that to the desired value.

```
set timezone = 'Asia/Kolkata';
select current_date;
```

Though this will return a date-only value, with the time set to midnight.  If you want the current date and time in a specific time zone, then:

```
set timezone = 'Asia/Kolkata';
select localtimestamp
```

See [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES) and [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) in the Postgres docs.

Comment: Jhonson thanks buddy. I have tried alternate way and it is working. I tried as follows: `select now() AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Kolkata'`